# JS alert function with multiple line string

Tags: javascript, alert

I have a php function which generates a javascript alert popup.

This function accepts a parameter message.
My problem is that if message is a multiple line string, javascript won't alert the text because of the lack of '+' every line. How can I solve that?

```
function alert($msg) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$msg.'")</script>';
}

/* DOESN'T WORK */
  $msg = 'testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest.
      testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest.
      testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest.';
  alert($msg);

/* WORKS */
  $msg = 'testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest. testtesttesttesttesttest. testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestttesttesttesttesttesttest.';
  alert($msg);
```

Comment: Why -1? Isn't this a serious question?!? @Pilot can you explain me why `/`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is multiline strings in javascript need to be split with a `\` at the end of each line.

```
function alert($msg) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$msg.'")</script>';
}

$msg = 'testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest.\
      testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest.\
      testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest.';
alert($msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please user `json_encode` function in pass function parameter
json_code function is change link break into `\n`

```
<?php 
 function alert($msg) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert('.$msg.')</script>';
}

/* DOESN'T WORK */
  $msg = 'testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest.
      testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest.
      testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest.';
  alert(json_encode($msg));
 ?>
```

This chrome
[image]

Comment: This won't work. The problem is the multiline string, not the function parameter.

Comment: @jamesj, `json_encode` function will add `\r\n` of line break so it will work

Comment: But the line above there isn't valid javascript. Try pasting it into the chrome dev console. It gives me `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: @jamesj please see attachment image, i used same code

Comment: Executing it as a php script first though. Nowhere does the question mention PHP (although I now notice that is what OP was using).